# Using Identity Token instead of Access Token for authorization on resource server

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

We are working on switching to **Cognito** as the 3rd party *OAuth 2.0 provider* for our backend services.

Our legacy system had its own **Spring Authorization Server** ([deprecated](https://spring.io/projects/spring-security-oauth)) for generating and verifying access tokens which enabled us to add custom claims to *Access Token* itself, there was no need to carry around *Id Token* to extract information about the authorised user.

But Cognito pushes us to use *OAuth 2.0* standards naturally, and **there is no possibility to add custom claims to Access Tokens**. Id Tokens are used for extracting custom claims and user information throughout an authorised session.

This brings us to a situation where we need to have Id tokens in the backend service sessions for the endpoints that needs some user info in order to process requests. But to fetch the Id token from the Cognito provided `/userInfo` endpoint, Access Tokens need to have `openid` scope, but to have the openid scope in the Access token, we need to use [Cognito Hosted UI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-app-integration.html) which is not applicable for the mobile app and our legacy Web app.

So either we need to use Identity Token as *the Bearer token*(not advised by standards), or we need to expect ID token with a custom HTTP header along with the Access token. Is there a huge security risk if ID tokens are used also for enabling access to REST API's ?

Comment: Why isn't Cognito Hosted UI applicable to mobile and web apps? Also, might look like a troll comment, but have you considered using another authorization-server which allows you to add private claims to access-tokens (and not just to ID-tokens) ?

Comment: You can't use ID-tokens, as they usually have a very short life time (like 5 minutes in some systems) and also they can't be refreshed using the refresh token. they are not meant to be used outside the client.

Comment: @ToreNestenius id token lifetime is configurable, so its not a problem https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-id-token.html , I'm just trying to understand if there is any risk involved, or its just a convention :)

Comment: @ch4mp its applicable, but we have a legacy system and replacing the login screen with Cognito Hosted UI is not very straightforward. We've considered couple of candidates but other SaaS solutions are very expensive for us right now

Comment: Yes, the lifetime is configurable but you can't get a new one unless you ask the user to re-authenticate. Some API't also look for the type claim in the token and many systems today uses the   "typ": "at+JWT", claim.

Comment: Using "hosted UI" should just be a matter of redirects. For mobile apps, this can be done with a web-view or system browser and a "deep-link". Nothing very complicated. Also there are excellent client libs out there which handle all the grunt work and require just a little conf.

Comment: @ch4mp thanks a lot for the tips, I'll dig deeper on that direction